# remove <br> tags at mobile or under specific resolutions

Tags: jquery, css

```
 $("br").remove();
```

I know the above..

But how could I specify the above code to run between `@media(max-width:700px) and (min-width:100px)` **..ONLY!**

Comment: to my knowledge i don't think you can trigger javascript from css, you can use javascript libraries to achieve the same effect

Comment: for the media queries css rule `br{display:none}` or maybe `display:inline`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jh7p5cba/2/) (note that the fiddle has min width of 200px so the fiddle could reach it...)

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 100px) and (max-width: 700px) {
    br {
        display: none;
    }
}
```